# mysql - a way to check if query is update/delete/create or select

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there a simple way to check if i should use `executeUpdate` or `executeQuery`.

Currenty i do this, but its kind of a mess

```
try
{
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query.query);
        //parse result
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        if(Messages.getString("Statement.57").equals(e.getMessage()))
        {
            final int rowsAffected = st.executeUpdate(query.query);
        }
        else
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
catch (final SQLException e)
{
    //error handling
}
```

Comment: `executeQuery` works for all 4 crud actions

Comment: No it doesnt, i get message mentioned above `Messages.getString("Statement.57")` `Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().`

Comment: my bad, executeNonQuery is the one that works

Comment: @PhiterFernandes There is no such method as `executeNonQuery().` What are you talking about?

Comment: A small library class around database access is done incredibly often. That however often neglects database vendor independence, prepared statments, SQL injection, type-safe parameters, O/R mapping and such matured features. A tip: `try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) { .... try (ResultSet rs = ...) { ... } }`

Answer (score 3):

When you don't know in advance what type of query you are executing, then you should use `execute` instead of `executeUpdate` or `executeQuery`. Make sure you interpret the meaning of the boolean return value correctly: `true` means the (first) result is a `ResultSet` and `false` means the (first) result is an update count. On some database systems you can have multiple result sets interleaved with update counts. You can usually ignore ignore this distinction.

So use:

```
boolean isResultSet = statement.execute(aDynamicStatement);
if (isResultSet) {
    try (ResultSet rs = rs.getResultSet()) {
        // Process result set
    }
} else {
    int updateCount = statement.getUpdateCount();
    // do something with update count
}
```

If you want or need to process multiple results (usually only with stored procedures, and only on systems that support this), you need to modify this to:

```
boolean isResultSet = statement.execute(aDynamicStatement);
while (true) {
    if (isResultSet) {
        try (ResultSet rs = rs.getResultSet()) {
            // Process result set
        }
    } else {
        int updateCount = statement.getUpdateCount();
        if (updateCount == -1) {
            // No more results, exit while loop
            break;
        }
        // do something with update count
    }
    isResultSet = statement.getMoreResults();
}
```

See also the apidoc of:

- [`Statement.execute(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-)
- [`Statement.getMoreResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--)
- [`Statement.getUpdateCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount--)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't give yourself this problem in the first place. You should design your wrapper API so that you provide separate access to the `executeQuery()` and `executeUpdate()` methods. The caller will know which he needs: don't lose that information by making your API too narrow.

Comment: Its not an API, it an app which has text field in which user can input query.

Comment: And you're going to allow the user to execute database updates? Really? Terrible feature, but if so, get them to tick a checkbox to select whether it's a query or an update.

Comment: It's not a terrible feature. It's and SQL manager app. You input your own db configuration(server, port, username....). Adding check box is non intuitive. Take phpmyadmin as an example. Do they have check box for this.

Comment: I don't know. Do they? and why are you reimplementing `phpmyadmin`? and HeidiSQL? and ...

Comment: No they don't, and it wasn't a question, i was trying to explain that its not what i want to do. No offence, but my question wasn't if i could avoid doing this, it was if i could improve what i already did. And btw I'm not re-implementing phpmyadmin/heidisql, im creating my own solution for android platform....

Comment: @pedja says-it's an app in which user can input query---- user :-)  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Your_TableName;  :) just for fun..